# Does exist Zend Filter similar to Zend Validator Identical?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-filter

Does exist Zend Filter similar to Zend Validator Identical?

The case  I should  filter input=='test'

```
$el->addFilter('Identical','test');
```

The problem that such filter not exist.

Thanks,
Yosef

Comment: Could you provide more information, since it is not clear how your filtering would work, maybe some example. Anyway, you could create your own filter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure how this filter should work, since it is not clear from your question. Anyway, I made some custom filter that will check if a value of input filed is equal to some $token. If they are equal than the input value will be empty string.

The filter looks as follows:

```
// file: APPLICATION_PATH/filters/Identical.php 

class My_Filter_Identical implements Zend_Filter_Interface {

    /**
     * Token with witch input is compared
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_token;

    /**
     * Set token
     *
     * @param  string
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($token = '') {
        $this->_token = $token;
    }

    /**
     * Filtering method 
     *
     * @param string $value value of input filed
     * @return string
     */
    public function filter($value) {

        if ($value !== $this->_token) {
            return $value;
        }

        return '';
    }

}
```

To apply it to a given form element:

```
require_once (APPLICATION_PATH . '/filters/Identical.php');
$el1->addFilter(new My_Filter_Identical('test'));
```

Off course instead of require_once it could be added to your resource autoloader, but as an  example I think it is not needed right now.

Edit:

Forgot to mention pregReplace filter.
The same what the custom filter above does could be done using pregReplace filter:

```
$el1->addFilter('pregReplace',array('/test/',''));
```

But, as I said, I'm not sure how you want your filter to work. If you provide more info maybe I could help more.

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't all that clear - do you want a filter which removes the word `test`? Or are you talking about filtering a form input? So taking your example you want to remove from the `el` input what the `test` input contains?

If you want to remove test from your input, you could use [Zend_Filter_PregReplace](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.filter.set.html)

```
$filter = new Zend_Filter_PregReplace(array('match' => '/test/', 'replace' => ''));
$input  = 'What is this test about!';
$filter->filter($input);
```

Should give you `What is this  about!`

There isn't a filter which would filter identical form input if its been entered into another input I don't think. You could try to create your own [input filter](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.filter.writing_filters.html) and perform your own logic on the input.

Comment: I don't want to use PregReplace, I need to remove all input, soo its not good to use regex. I know that I can make my own filter, but I don't know if I can use filter that exist already in zend framework

Answer (score 1):

It is not that clear what you are trying to do. If you give more explanation that would be good.

> I need to remove all input, soo its not good to use regex.

If you just want to clear the data in form elements you can use one of the following:

1. Clear an element value by setting the value of the element to nothing.

   $el->setValue(null);
2. or reset all form elements

   $form->reset();

Comment: remove only if input equal to == 'somevalue'

Comment: Then use custom filter as in Marcin's answer